# How do I get to Abant Lake from Istanbul?

Tags: public-transport, turkey, istanbul, lakes

I'm planning to go to Istanbul and I heard that Abant Lake is nice throughout the year. So, I'm planning to go there for a day as well. What worries me is how to go from Bolu to Abant Lake. I found a lot of information how to go from Istanbul to Bolu by bus, but what about from Bolu to Abant. Do I need to book any bus in advance? Or should I just turn up there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public transportation connecting Abant Lake to Bolu or any other city. You can either rent a car and go there yourself or find a tour from Bolu or even from Istanbul that takes you there. Other option would be renting a car with a driver from the hotel directly (this is done in all Turkish hotels easily), this is the most expensive option but at the same time it is the most convenient one.